# Intermittent Windows Server 2008 BSOD and restart

Tags: windows-server-2008, amazon-ec2, bsod

Our EC2 Instance (Windows Server 2008) crashed multiple times for the past 3 months (last time was today at 1:05 EST). Upon reviewing MEMORY.DMP file we noticed that possible cause of the crashes is rhelnet.sys (RedHat PV NIC Driver).

Server's Event Viewer has the following records right after the crash:

```
Critical - Kernel Power:
The system has rebooted without cleanly shutting down first. 
This error could be caused if the system stopped responding, crashed, or lost power unexpectedly.

BugCheck:
The computer has rebooted from a bugcheck.  The bugcheck was:
0x000000d1 (0x000000000000002d, 0x0000000000000002, 0x0000000000000000, 0xfffff88001402d14). 
A dump was saved in: C:\Windows\MEMORY.DMP. Report Id: 100113-35849-01.
```

Could this be a hardware issue? Would it help if we stop and start the instance? Or is this more likely that this is caused by the software running on the system?

**[Update 10.01.2013]**

Amazon Rep suggested to update RH drivers to Citrix PV drivers on our instance:

[Upgrading PV Drivers](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/Upgrading_PV_drivers.html#win2008-citrix-upgrade)

**[Update 10.08.2013]**

We performed a drivers upgrade on the cloned instance. Right after the upgrade we noticed the following errors in our Event viewer:

```
Xennet6 errors in Event Viewer (Event ID# 5001)
```

After digging a bit more I found [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/500052/can-i-safely-uninstall-citrix-tools-for-virtual-machines) article suggesting to install the latest Citrix drivers. Unfortunately, this didn't help us at all and our cloned instance became unresponsive.

**[Update 10.08.2013 2]**

I recreated an instance and updated PV drivers again. 
After searching on Internet I found [this](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=477921) article where Amazon Rep explains that:

```
"Event ID 5001 from source Xennet6 cannot be found" message does not 
indicate anything wrong, just that the PV driver is looking for a feature
that we have not implemented in our version of Xen.
```

I will keep my test system running for a while to see if there any issues with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrading drivers as suggested by Amazon Rep fixed the isuse.

In regards to `Event ID 5001...` issue below is the reply I've got from Amazon:

```
Please ignore the Xennet 5001 error. This error occurs on every instance
that is launched with Citrix PV drivers and is due to the driver looking
for a feature that is not supported on EC2. It will have no other effect on the instance.
```

Answer (score 1):

I got same issue.

But AWS Supporter answer me as below, They don't sure issue from Citrix PV drives.

```
Currently, we are unable to root cause the issue.
In my personal opinion, this might be a one-time only occurrence,
but as you are running Citrix PV Drivers, I highly encourage you to upgrade.

As the Citrix drivers show up in the logs,
they might had been related to the issue.
```